# Экспорт Excel-файла из админки Django с verbose-именами

Tags: python, django, excel, django-admin

Я использую `DjangoObjectActions` из `django_object_actions` пакета для того, чтобы добавить кнопку "Экспортировать в Эксель" в админке Django.

```
class QueryAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def export_to_xls(self, request, obj):
        query_record = Query.objects.all().values('profile__full_name')
        return excel.make_response_from_records(
            query_record,
            'xlsx',
            file_name="Querys"
        )

    list_display = ('weight', 'height')
    export_to_xls.label = "Export to Excel"
    changelist_actions = ('export_to_xls',)
```

Существует ли способ, чтобы экспортировать таблицу с **verbose names**? Было бы очень удобно, если бы можно было на русском видеть названия колонок, а не именами переменных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не нашел способа экспортировать таблицу так, как я хотел. Поэтому я воспользовался JS библиотекой DataTables (https://datatables.net), добавил в админке страницу с таблицей, которую я хотел, сделанной с этой библиотекой и к ней добавил кнопки для экспорта.